# Unable to format my 16GB USB stick to NTFS (or EXT4 on Linux)

Tags: windows-10, usb-flash-drive, ntfs, ext4, raspbian

I have a Sandisk Cruzer Blade 16GB, and i simply cant format it to NTFS on Windows (10, and i already did the "Method 3" in [this tutorial](https://www.easeus.com/partition-master/format-usb-flash-drive-to-ntfs.html)), nor format it on a Raspberry Pi using fdisk and mkfs to EXT4 (the stick wont mount, just spill the error `wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdx1`).

Interestingly, i can format without problems to FAT32 on Windows and to EXT3 on Linux without problem, but anyway i came here because i fear the stick could be corrupted to store data on it.

So, the device is corrupted OR this is a problem in formatting a usb stick to these file formats? Because i have plans to use this as a data drive on my raspberry pi, so ext4 would be the prefered format.

**EDIT**: According to Tetsujin: *"I was wondering if the firmware protect had kicked in, but that seems unlikely."*

Comment: Using FAT32 as filesystem: Copied 3 excel spreadsheets in Windows 10; after copy tried to eject the stick using the taskbar window: not work (the 'Volume' is being used at the moment), so i removed anyway; after that i reinserted and the files are still there; in Raspbian using this same fat32 the files show up as well.

Comment: I was also able to "format" a supposedly 1TB USB stick with FAT and exFAT despite the fact that it was actually a cheap broken piece of hardware that stopped working after the first 100GB. When you format with NTFS it actually has to write a bit at half and at the end of the drive so if the drive is damaged it won't work.